# File::open() panics when file doesn't exist

Tags: file, rust

I'm running this:

```
use std::error::Error;
use std::fs::File;

fn main() {
    try_main().unwrap();
}

fn try_main() -> Result<(), Box<Error>> {
    try!(check_file("andre"));
    Ok(())
}

fn check_file(user: &str) -> Result<(), Box<Error>> {
    let suspend_file_name = format!("{}{}", "/var/cpanel/suspended/", user);
    let suspend_file = try!(File::open(suspend_file_name));

    Ok(())
}
```

And getting this error:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" }', libcore/result.rs:945:5
```

I thought this was supposed to return an error? I am using Rust 1.3 and have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Off-topic, but you should use [`PathBuf`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.PathBuf.html) to construct paths instead of `format!`.

Comment: Thanks @Shepmaster for the PathBuf recommendation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your program is doing exactly what you have told it to. Check this version:

```
use std::{error::Error, fs::File, path::PathBuf};

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<Error>> {
    let x = check_file("andre");
    println!("{}", x.is_ok());
    Ok(())
}

fn check_file(user: &str) -> Result<(), Box<Error>> {
    let mut suspend_file_name = PathBuf::from("/var/cpanel/suspended/");
    suspend_file_name.push(user);
    let _suspend_file = File::open(suspend_file_name)?;

    Ok(())
}
```

The output will be `false`, which indicates that the result of `check_file` was an `Err`. If you [`unwrap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.unwrap) that:

> Panics if the value is an `Err`, with a panic message provided by the `Err`'s value.

`File::open` doesn't panic, but the *method that explicitly says it will panic* on an `Err` value does indeed panic on an `Err` value.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't realize unwrap did that. I have a lot of reading to do.